# laravel 5.1 error TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, token

I try to authentication users. I type code and do steps like documentation laravel but have the error. This is my form

enter code here

```
{!! csrf_field() !!} 
First Name Last Name E-mail Address Sport: {{ $gametype }}>   
@foreach($games as $game) 
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ old('game_type_id') }}"> {{ $game->name }}>
@endforeach
```

Password Password Confirmation I agree with terms of use Sign Up Sign Up or Connect with Connect with Already have an account? Sign In!

This is route: // Authentication routes...

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');      
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

// Registration routes...

```
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'); 
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

My files login and register blade are in view/auth folder. When I registered get this error TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection), you have to use and input field with the current token.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" />
```

and use `Route::controller('auth','AuthController');` instead of all your current routes.